# What could cause my Apple developer role to unexplainably change from admin to manager?

Tags: ios, xcode, software-distribution, ad-hoc-distribution

I started our company's Apple dev account in 2018, setting myself as admin
Lately (2022), I could not distribute to the team because my role had been changed to "manager".

I changed back to "admin" and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

A team mate admitted to changing it.

He changed it back to admin, and all is well.